# Javascript dynamic div height based on window height and second div height

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, html

How do i modify the below code so that instead of minusing 210 is minuses another div height so that the equation essentially becomes "main-menu = window height - div height"?

```
$('#main-menu').css({'height':(($(window).height())-210)+'px'});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yM8wG/1/)

Markup like this:

```
​<div id="main-menu"></div>
<div id="other-div">
    <h1>Sample Content</h1>
    <p>
        foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar 
    </p>
</div>​
```

Css like this:

```
​#other-div {
    background: #cdcdcd;
}​
```

Javascript like this:

```
$('#main-menu').height($(window).height()-$("#other-div").height());​
```

As you can see from the script, I call the height function.

Comment: Nah, the height of that div isn't fixed, it's based on the content isnt it.